# How to center or set position of an Xbox Game Bar Widget?

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

How could I set the default position of an Xbox Game Bar Widget?

In particular, I would like my Widget to load in the center of the screen but having all control of the Widget's position would be fantastic.

Comment: As far as I know, UWP does not provide the corresponding API for setting the initial position of the widget. You can find the settings of the widget in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/game-bar/guide/pkg-manifest#optional-properties), but it does not provide the position property.

You can ask this question in [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/XboxGameBarSamples/issues)

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave this open incase anyone wants to add to this but I did also correspond on the open issue there and hopefully they prioritize the feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Since the UWP xaml is basically `Page` thers is no property of `Top` and `Left`. But `XboxGameBarWidget` class has `CenterWindowAsync()` method instead that derived from `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction` interface. That method centers gamebar widget in the screen. If you want to center the position on load, put the method in `OnNavigatedTo()` because it is called automatically on load.

> ```
> protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
> {
>      widget = e.Parameter as XboxGameBarWidget;
>      await widget.CenterWindowAsync();
> }
> ```

here is the [microsoft API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/game-bar/api/xgb-widget). you can find `CenterWindowAsync()` and its detailed description